# The number of solutions for $|x^2-5|x|+6|=|\cos x|$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I wish to find the number of solutions for $|x^2-5|x|+6|=|\cos x|$ graphically

I can graph $|\cos x|$ to some accuracy but struggle in graphing $|x^2-5|x|+6|$

Is this question solvable graphically? If so could a method to sketch the graph be given.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: $x^2-5|x|+6=(|x|-2)(|x|-3)$

Comment: When $x\ge 0$ it is just $|x^2-5x+6|$. When $x\le 0$ it is just $|(-x)^2-5(-x)+6|$, which is the former graph symmetrically mapped across the $y$ axis. Does it help?

Comment: First thing to note: Both sides are symmetric with respect to $x=0$. So you can only look at $x\geq 0$ ...

Comment: @Stinking Bishop very much ,thanks alot .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x^2 - 5x + 6 \implies |x^2-5|x|+6| = |f(|x|)|$

So to graph $|x^2-5|x|+6|$:

- Graph $f(x) = x^2 - 5x + 6$

[image]

- Graph $f(|x|)$: Remove the graph on the left side of $y-axis$, then take symmetric with respect to $y-axis$ of the right side of $y-axis$ to the left

[image]

- Graph $|f(|x|)|$: Take symmetric with respect to $x-axis$ of the below of $x-axis$ (where $y$ is negative) to the top

[image]

(Red is $f(x)$, green is $f(|x|)$, purple is $|f(|x|)|$

Now graph $|\cos x|$ and you will see that there are $4$ different solutions:

[image]

Comment: Thank for the step by step explaination sir ,I should have accepted it earlier .But I could not understand in the second step why we remove that part of the graph.

Comment: @Glowingbluejuicebox Well it's $f(|x|)$, so $f(|-1|) = f(|1|) = f(1), f(|-2|) = f(|2|) = f(2), ...$, therefore the value of $f(|x|)$ when $x$ is negative is the same as when $x$ is positive, or in another word: the graph on the left side of y-axis should be the reflection of the graph on the right side. You could try out some values for $x$ to see that!

Answer (score 3):

To plot $y=|x^2-5|x|+6|$ you first plot

$y=x^2-5x+6$ and $y=x^2+5x+6$, then take the arc in the first quadrant for the first and in the second for the second.

Then you take the symmetric wrt $x$-axis of the negative parts, where $y$ is negative I mean.

Both function are even. Solutions are
$\pm 1.8054,\pm 3.5757$

[image]

---

$$
$$
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**To Plot the Graphs**

$x^2-5|x|+6$ and $\cos(x)$ are even functions, so plot $\left|\,x^2-5x+6\,\right|$ and $|\cos(x)|$ for $x\ge0$, and then reflect across the $y$-axis. Therefore, for $x\ge0$, plot $x^2-5x+6$ and $\cos(x)$ and reflect their graphs across the $x$-axis where they are negative (dashed graphs), and then reflect across the $y$-axis.

[image]

The graphs intersect at $4$ points.

---

**To Find the Points of Intersection**

Since the functions are even, we can find the points of intersection for $x\ge0$ and reflect them across the $y$-axis (as we did the graphs). Note that, for $x\ge0$, the graph of $x^2-5x+6$ (not its reflection) intersects the graph of $-\cos(x)$ (the reflection of $\cos(x)$) at two points. So using Newton's Method (or whatever root finding algorithm you wish), solve
$$
x^2-5x+6=-\cos(x)
$$
to get the roots
$$
(1.80540492,0.23246232)\quad\text{and}\quad(3.57574485,0.90722699)
$$
whose $y$-reflections are
$$
(-1.80540492,0.23246232)\quad\text{and}\quad(-3.57574485,0.90722699)
$$